# collision detection not working right

Tags: java, math, trigonometry, collision

Okay, so my paddle collision is working fine:

```
if(velo.y > 0){
            float t = ((position.y - radius) - paddle.position.y)/ velo.y;

            float ballHitX = position.x + velo.x * t;

            if(t <= 1.0){
                if(ballHitX >= paddle.position.x && ballHitX <= paddle.position.x + paddle.width){
                    velo.y = -velo.y;
                }
            }
        }
```

But my wall collision isn't. (the ball goes up when under the paddle, and down when not)

```
if(velo.y < 0){
                float t = ((position.y - radius) - (wall[2].y + wall[2].height))/ velo.y;

                if(t <= 1.0){
                velo.y = -velo.y;
                }
            }
```

How do I stop this error and make it so the ball bounces off the wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're flipping it twice.

```
if(wall) {
    velo = -velo;
}
if(paddle) {
    velo = -velo;
}
```

So, when you do your paddle, it goes like this:

```
am i hitting the wall? nope
am i hitting the paddle? yep! okay flip velocity
```

But when you do your wall, it goes like this:

```
am i hitting the wall? yep! okay flip velocity
am i hitting the paddle? yep! okay flip velocity
```

So because yu're hitting both conditions, it flips twice.

You need to determine whether or not you've flipped already to prevent double flippage.